# PWA Install App or Add to Home screen using beforeinstallprompt cannot trigger more than 1 times

Tags: installation, progressive-web-apps, prompt, beforeinstallprompt

Im developing a PWA and i want to add button to trigger the A2HS dialog like this image. [image]

I found that i can only trigger it 1 times and i need to clear my chrome data to trigger the event again. i want to show this dialog every time when the user click the install button that i have in my home screen. How to show the pop up multiple times.

i want user can view the promotion install button that i make to trigger the add to home screen pop up multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the event and use it later multiple times. It's explained [here](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation-prompt).

I use React and [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) as state manager. I save the event into a store

```js
/* Saves PWA install prompt for future usage */
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  useMyStore.setState({ pwaInstallPrompt: event });
});
```

Then in my custom InstallPwaModal component I do:

```js
const { pwaInstallPrompt, setIsPwaInstallModalOpen } = useMyStore((state) => ({
  pwaInstallPrompt: state.pwaInstallPrompt,
  setIsPwaInstallModalOpen: state.setIsPwaInstallModalOpen,
}));

const handleInstallButtonClick = async () => {
  const result = await pwaInstallPrompt.prompt();
  setIsPwaInstallModalOpen(result.outcome !== 'accepted');
};
```